# How to count all users in reverse relationship

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Using Django ORM I would like to create a method on Company which returns the User count.

This is what I have tried (see company_user_count method):

**User Model:**

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    ) 
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name="users")
```

**Company Model:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


    def company_user_count(self):
        return Company.objects.filter(users__company=self.company).annotate(user_count=Count('users'))
```

Above seems to return an actual object and not a simple count (int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def company_user_count(self):
    return self.users.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a custom method for counting users that belong to a company.

Just get all of the company's users and execute `count()` on them.

```
user_count = Company.objects.get(name='fooCompany').users.count()
```

Comment: See the documentation on how [`get` works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) - its not the same as the dictionary method `get` which I think is what you understand it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def company_user_count(self):
    return self.users.count()
```

Comment: Duplicate answer to Simon's.

Comment: Posted at exactly the same time